# General questions about various experiences with Magento (the company)

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to ask questions about Magento (Magento, Inc., an eBay Company (X.Commerce)) ?

It would be a great place to find out what other people (Magento Partners, Magento customers)   experienced in their relation with Magento , Inc.
Extremly curious about Magento Partners experience with Magento Support.

Comment: This might be a bit difficult to answer without specific examples. Magento SE is an applied site about problems you encounter in your day-to-day work. I having trouble envisioning what type of constructive (non chatty) questions you might have about the company. Asking about other people's experience in general doesn't always align well with this type of Q&A, but again, without specific examples, I am hesitant to offer advice one way or the other.

Comment: You would certainly want to phrase your questions tactfully.

Answer (score 1):

I can envisage some relevant questions that would fall under this

- What requirements do I need to meet to be partner level X?
- What is the SLA response time for a support ticket?

But you would have to be careful with some questions about Magento specifically - as answers could put them in a very bad light indeed.

We (as a company) have had a lot more negative experiences with Magento Inc. than positive (in fact, I can think of *no* positive experiences from any perspective as a Partner or on behalf of our EE Clients). But whether we can (or will) go into detail to document this publicly is another thing.

Not many companies would want to risk 'rocking the boat' by posting something negative - so the answers could be not entirely accurate.

Mind you, I'd love to see answers to questions down this vein - to see if they mirrored or contrasted with our own experiences. But I'm not 100% sure it would ever fit into the Q&A format of the website.

Comment: one of the questions I am thinking of is how to go through their support system and get a solution for a Magento bug, when you provide them in depth technical info. What to expect from their Marketing/Sales department and so on.

Comment: I don't see why not - especially since the question you are asking isn't documented anywhere. I think it would be of benefit to the community at large.

Comment: Both of your example questions would be met with "Google it" or "What have you tried?"

Comment: @philwinkle you could probably answer every question posted on this site with comments like that :\

Comment: @sonassi touché